# How to convert currency using native Shopify converter?

Tags: javascript, shopify, currency

As the title states, I'm using Shopify. I'm able to convert the currency from USD to another, but the currency it's self is still 20 in value, if it's $20 USD it's 20 in any other currency.

```
Shopify.formatMoney(2000)
```

I also found this in my theme.js

```
Currency.moneyFormats[Shopify.currency.active]["money_format"]
```

But this returns

```
{{amount}} USD
```

I also found this

```
<!— layout/theme.liquid —>

{% if template contains 'product' %}


<!— … Your stuff … —>

{{ "/services/javascripts/currencies.js" | script_tag }}

<script>
    
    // Set the current price
    var price = {{ current_variant.price }}
    
    // Returns the current (approximate) price in Euros
    function getEuros() {
        return (Currency.convert(price, 'GBP', 'EUR')/100).toFixed(2);
    }
    
    // looks for an element with an ID of "euroPrice" and replaces the content with a sring
    document.getElementByID('euroPrice').html = '€' + getEuros() + ' EUR' 
    
    </script>

{% endif %}
```

So would I have to build functionality to convert each currency? I figured this would be built into Shopify?